Question about a proof of integer solution for $x^2 + y^3 = z^6$
In this proof of integer solutions for $x^2 + y^3 = z^6$

Let $(x,y,z)$ be a solution with minimal $|z|$. from equation we derive that $(z^3-x)(z^3+x)=y^3$. Obviously $\gcd (x,y)=\gcd(y,z)=\gcd(z,x)=1$. Thus there are coprime integers $a,b$ such that $z^3-x=a^3$ and $z^3+x=b^3$ and therefore $a^3+b^3=2z^3$, or there are coprime integers $a,b$ such that $z^3-x=2a^3$ and $z^3+x=4b^3$ and therefore $z^3+(-a)^3=2b^3$.
In both cases we are left with an equation of type $a^3+b^3=2z^3$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$. let $|z|$ be minimal (assume that $|z|\ne0$). $a$
and $b$ must be odd. now substitute $a=u+v$ and
$b=u-v$, where $u$ and $v$ are coprime integers and from different parity. then $u (u^2+3v^2)= z^3$ and so there are integers $r,s$ such that $u = r^3$ and $u^2+3v^2= s^3$.
From this, we have $(u+\sqrt{-3}v)(u-\sqrt{-3}v)=s^3$. treating this equation in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$, you can reach a equation of the form $a_0^3+b_0^3=2z_0^3$, where $|z_0|<|z|$, unless $a=b$ (or $|z|=0$) which yields the solutions $(x,y,z)=(\pm 3k^3,-2k^2,\pm k)$.

In the last step, "treating this equation in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$", how can I reach an equation of the form $a_0^3+b_0^3=2z_0^3$?
But $\mathbb Z[ \sqrt{-3}]$ is not a UFD.
I think I need to work in the larger ring $\mathbb{Z}[ω],ω=\frac{\sqrt{-3}-1}{2}$.
Using $u,v$ are coprime and from different parity, $\gcd(u+\sqrt{-3}v,u-\sqrt{-3}v)$ divides $\sqrt{-3}$.
If $u+\sqrt{-3}v,u-\sqrt{-3}v$ are coprime, since $\mathbb{Z}[ω]$ is a PID, $u\pm\sqrt{-3}v$ equals a unit times a cube in $\mathbb{Z}[ω]$.
$\mathbb{Z}[ω]$ has six units: $\pm1,\pm ω,\pm ω^2$.
If $u+\sqrt{-3}v=a_0^3,u-\sqrt{-3}v=b_0^3$ for some $a_0,b_0\in\mathbb{Z}[ω]$, then $a_0^3+b_0^3=2u$, how to prove $a_0,b_0\in\Bbb Z$?
If $u+\sqrt{-3}v=ωa_0^3,u-\sqrt{-3}v=ω^2b_0^3$, then?
